# Hide “Ship to a Different Address?” text and checkbox in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

It is necessary to hide “Ship to a Different Address?” text and checkbox in Woocommerce checkout.
It means that only these elements of form should disappear without any changes to shipping fields.
So  “Ship to a Different Address?” checkbox must be checked but simply invisible.
How to do it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can hide it with css...

Comment: why you don't want to ship to to billing address if the user can't use a different address?

Answer (score 2):

Hiding of “Ship to a Different Address?” text and checkbox in Woocommerce checkout was successfully done by editing form-shipping.php file.
Instead of these lines

```
<h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
        <label for="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" />
    </h3>
```

we should add these ones

```
<h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
        <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" style="display:none;" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" />
    </h3>
```